# I am trying to rerwrite this as a mysqli query but I keep getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I wrote a query in PHP and mysql and it works fine and returns data I am just trying to re-write it as a Mysqli function.

This is what I come up with but I get a 500 error with the file.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Could not talk to the database: ", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query("SQL QUERY WORKS FINE");
$data = array();
if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
    $tempData = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempData = $row;
        array_push($data, $tempData);
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
/* free result set */
$result->close();
$con->close();
```

Comment: Is there anything in your server's error logs?

Comment: I am just checking that right now. It just doesnt make sense. I have a similar query running on a different file except it doesn't encode the results and that works fine.

Comment: You can also try running the PHP file directly from the command line - that'll output the error onto the screen for you.

Comment: What is `$query("SQL QUERY WORKS FINE");` supposed to do?  Is there an anonymous function assigned to `$query`?

Comment: It is just the SQL Text @Crontab

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see is that you are trying to **json_encode** a variable that does not exist. change `$myArray` to `$tempData` ?

If your debugging is turned off the error message would go into error_log saying undefined variable **$myArray**